# Use User ID to mention someone on Slack

Tags: json, curl, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use [user.lookupByEmail](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail#examples) to be able to mention an individual user on Slack through a Jenkins pipeline. I have a the message block setup outside of the pipeline itself. I am able to hit the Slack API on Postman to get the proper JSON. But when I try to use the curl from Postman I am getting an exitValue of 3 and the output is empty. Here is the code that I am currently working with:

```
[Updated]
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper


def emailCommand = 'git log -1 --pretty=format:"%ae"'
def emailProcess = emailCommand.execute()
def committerEmail = emailProcess.text.trim().replaceAll(/['"]/,'')

JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()

def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
def err = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
def curlCommand = "curl --location 'https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail?email=${committerEmail}' \
--header 'Authorization: ${jenkinsSecret}'"

def processCurl = curlCommand.execute()
processCurl.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
processCurl.waitFor()

def curlOutput = processCurl.text
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(curlOutput)

println(parsedJson)
```

I have hard coded the JSON output from Postman as its own variable to test parsing through it and then used `String idValue = parsedJson.user.id` to get the ID need.

I am expecting there to be a JSON output that can be parsed using a format like `idValue`.

With the updated code I am now getting this error:

```
error stream was curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname
```

Comment: Does this do what you need? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/slack/#slackuseridfromemail-resolve-slack-userid-from-email-address

Comment: @MaratC we aren't wanting to use the plugin. We didn't use the legacy Slack bot. We created our own. We are using a `MessageFactory.groovy` file to create the message.

Comment: Except for noticing that `curl` error 3 means `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT (3) The URL was not properly formatted` there's not much I can help.

Comment: Understand. What stinks is that it is the cURL from Postman. I just replaced the my work email with a variable. It still doesn't work with the exact one from Postman. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: It could help to print your `curlCommand` before executing it and see if something's off.